# Requeired permission: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets - only when called by a function

Tags: google-apps-script

The function below works fine and save "Bla bla" in the target sheet (don't worry about stdParcels) if I run it directly from App Script Editor

```
   function saveParcels(stdParcels) {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id");
     var test = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname')
     test.getRange(4, 1, 1, 1).setValue('Bla Bla!')
   }
```

The same function did not work if it is called from the function

- saveParcels(stdParcels) on the same file - error:  Requeired permission.

Manifest:

```
{
    "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ],
    "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",

    "dependencies": {
    },
    "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
    "runtimeVersion": "V8"
  }
```

Any tip to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by calling from the function, anyway your scopes look a little bit strange, try removing "spreadsheets.currentonly" and leave "spreadsheets".

Comment: As you mentioned if we run this from the IDE no error's shown up so in oder to better help you, can you please give more info about this function? is this a trigger or a function called from another library? You said that we don't have to worry about stdParcels, it might be part of the issue though.